# How to fix table width in html 5?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

Check this image:

https://ibb.co/MhtZLpG

The problem is in my table my last column of my table is off the screen

I have tried

`<table style="width:200px !important">`

and

`<table style="width:20% !important">`

but it didn't work.

Comment: Try to reproduce the situation in a JSFiddle for example. It's hard to solve the problem if we can't see your html structure or css code.

Comment: are you using `bootstrap` or `jquery ui`

Comment: i am using bootstrap

Comment: here is my code : https://jsfiddle.net/1m54g0hz/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to set the `table-layout` explicitly:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Then, you can set the column width:

```
th:nth-child(<<the number of which column you want to set the width>>) {
  width: <<your desried width>>
}
```

And if you want to set the table width occupy the full width, then just set:

```
table {
  table-layout: auto;
}
```

What you're trying to do is to make like:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 20%;
}
```

Using inline, the following will work:

```
<table style="width:20%; table-layout: fixed;">
```

---

Here's the width classes that bootstrap 4 comes with:

```
w-25 /* width: 25%; */
w-50 /* width: 50%; */
w-75 /* width: 75%; */
w-100 /* width: 100%; */
```

To which you can apply to your table for the class. For eg. `class="w-25"`

You can also apply the column classes - `col-*`:

```
<table class="col-3">
```

Comment: Thnx mr. Bhojendra Rauniyar i really appriciate for giving answer quickly but it didn't work i already tried it

Comment: What is not working? I have tried to include most of the possible ways.

Comment: Don't forget to set `table-layout` even if you use bootstrap.

Comment: @Aeraz it works, where did you go wrong or what did you forget to tell us in your demo ? https://jsfiddle.net/t7hkqjbg/

Comment: i don't know where i am doing wrong but it didn't work for me thnx for helping guys

Comment: @Aeraz Glad to hear that you finally managed to resolve the issue.

Comment: @alexchvrches Glad, you get it helpful.